# Quickly compare before and after in Lightroom

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3

In Adobe Lightroom, is there a quick way to view the picture without the transforms applied? I'm looking for a single keypress or mouse click to toggle/switch between the pre and post transformed view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the \ key.  You should be able to figure this out by going to the View menu, Before/After and next to the menu items you'll see the shortcuts there.

More shortcuts here:  [Adobe Lightroom 3 shortcuts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Lightroom/3.0/Using/WS18e2013dd74eab5fe275e2711d1b186fe9-8000.html)